# Is possible to use run_instances from instance template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, aws-cli

I'd like to use a launch template with instance specifics then use it with run_instances to dispatch a number of similar instances. I have my reasons not to use Autoscaling.

I did the following

```
 ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2',aws_access_key_id = AWS_ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key = AWS_SECRET_KEY)

response = ec2_client.describe_key_pairs()
print(response)

lt = ec2_client.create_launch_template(
LaunchTemplateName='aLaunchTemplate',  
LaunchTemplateData={ 
    'EbsOptimized': True, 
    'IamInstanceProfile': {  
        'Arn': 'arn:aws:iam::*************:instance-profile/******',  
        'Name': '*******' 
    },    
    'ImageId': 'ami-*******', 
    'InstanceType': 't2.micro', 
    'KeyName': 'FirstKeyPair', 
    'Monitoring': { 
        'Enabled': True  
    },    
    'InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior': 'terminate',  
    'UserData': userData,  
     'SecurityGroupIds': [ 
        'sg-********' 
    ], 
    'SecurityGroups': [  
        'sg-********'  
    ] 
    })

launchTemplateName = lt['LaunchTemplate']['LaunchTemplateName']
launchTemplateId = lt['LaunchTemplate']['LaunchTemplateId']

print " Instance Template Name : " , "<",launchTemplateName,"> with <Id : ",launchTemplateId,">"

lt_specifics = {
    'LaunchTemplateId': launchTemplateId,
    'LaunchTemplateName': launchTemplateName,
    'Version': 'default'
}

launchedInstances = ec2_client.run_instances(MaxCount=2,MinCount=1,LaunchTemplate=lt_specifics)
```

This produced the following error :

> raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name) botocore.exceptions.ClientError : an error occurred (InvalidParameterCombination) When calling the RunInstances operation :  A launch template ID and a launch template name cannot be specified in the same request

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you remove either the `LaunchTemplateId` or `LaunchTemplateName` from your `lt_specifics` JSON which is used in the run_instances call and try it

Comment: @KrishnaKumarR  It doesn't work. The error now is : Either a launch template ID or a launch template name must be specified in the request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the [API documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_LaunchTemplateSpecification.html),

> You must specify either the launch template ID or launch template name
>   in the request

In your example you provide both.

You should only specify either the `LaunchTemplateId` or the `LaunchTemplateName`.

Try changing `lt_specifics` to

```
lt_specifics = {
    'LaunchTemplateId': launchTemplateId
}
```

The `Version` is not required and will default the the launch templates default